# Is there a way to create one function line to sum 2 complex vectors without creating a collection that is not of fixed length

Tags: python, lambda, inner-product

Implements a function in one line and without creating a list or tuples or any other collection that is not of fixed length and without using numpy using the given def signature

here what i did

```
def inner_product_c(c1: Iterable[complex], c2: Iterable[complex]) -> complex:
    return  list(map(lambda x, y: x*y.conjugate() , c1, c2)) ;
```

i define inner product space such that u,v are 2 vectors and i want the sum of all elements  accordingly to the same position where u(i) * conjugate(v(i))

here is the only one line way that i came up with
is there any other ways to do it in one line?

Answer (score 0):

In Python3:

```
def inner_product_c(c1: Iterable[complex], c2: Iterable[complex]) -> complex:                                                                                                                                                                                 
    return sum(list([c1[n]*c2[n].conjugate() for n in range(len(c1))]))
```

`range()` returns an iterator in Python3, with space-complexity `O(1)` Therefore the above does not create anything (other than the return list) of space-complexity `O(n)` (being n the length of the vectors)

Comment: Thank you, but this dose not return scalar as expected !

Comment: neither does your function, by the way

Comment: @danny - check last edit: the function returns indeed the inner product now (added `sum` around the list)